# How to set Layout margin to match other layout starting point

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a `listView` and i want to make a custom adapter which looks like this :

[image]

There is one `LinearLayout` for the picture and the name and two `RelativeLayout` for the `Cost` and `Duration` columns. My problem is that if the name is long it will overlay the cost and duration columns. Also i want to keep the Cost and Duration columns in the right of the row.

There is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/colorText">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pointImage"
        android:layout_width="20sp"
        android:layout_height="20sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/list" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/pointImage"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="Name" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/costLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="3sp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/durationLayout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/costLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/costLabel"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cost"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/costLabel"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="300€"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/durationLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="3sp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/durationLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="@string/durationLabel"/>
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/durationLabel"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="30 min" />
      </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Can I set `LinearLayout`'s right margin to be the starting point of `Cost` column or how can i avoid the overlaying?

Comment: An alternative to a `LinearLayout` might be using a `ConstraintLayout`. I find it *very* handy in a lot of situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `ConstraintLayout` for this. Doing so will let you avoid nested viewgroups (which is a performance increase that is most valuable in adapter views) and let you easily meet all the requirements specified in your question.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorText">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pointImage"
        android:layout_width="20sp"
        android:layout_height="20sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_archive"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/pointImage"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/costLabel"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/costLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="6sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="@string/costLabel"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/durationLabel"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/costLabel"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="300€"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/costLabel"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/costLabel"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/costLabel"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/durationLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="@string/durationLabel"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/duration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="30 min"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/durationLabel"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/durationLabel"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/durationLabel"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, i'll use `ConstraintLayout` as you recommend, but i don't understand how nested viewgroups will affect the performance can you explain me ?

Comment: In your posted code, there are 10 views: the six things the user will see, the three wrappers around each pair of things the user will see, and the overall parent. In my posted code, there are 7 views: the six things the user will see and the overall parent. This means less memory consumption (fewer objects) and faster drawing (fewer views to measure and lay out).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a LinearLayout and inside it work with weight attribute like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="2"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

More weight means more space.

Or you can set a character limit to the name and add "..." in the end.

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:ellipsize="end"/>
```

This text view can have only 10 chars and add "..." in the end if have more than 10 chars